# Magento downloadable product link empty

Tags: magento, hyperlink, product

we have a problem with our magento shop before going live. We do not exaclty know when did this one happen. We want to offer digital goods (pictures) as download links from external host.

Everything worked fine - we did not test the checkout for a month.

Now we have a problem, if customer buys a digital good, his download link for his picture does not work. It is empty. The hashkey in the DB seems ok. In Backend the purchase is being triggered. We suppose the connection between the hashkey and the external url is wrong.

We did 2 things since that but already applied a rollback. We installed SSL sertificate and a delete old orders extension. Can one of these things cause our problem?

Thank you a lot for any hint.

Best regards

Dimitri Petrik